# Eclipse color theme plugin issue

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I just installed the Eclipse color theme plugin and when I go to "Preferences-General-Appearance-Color Theme" and choose a new theme it does not change my colors.  I am testing this in both the "Web" and "JavaScript" perspectives.

Currently my background color is black (which it was not before, and I in fact have no idea how it got switched).  I just want to switch it back to a typical white theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out.  I also have Aptana Studio installed in my Eclipse.  Under the settings for Aptana Studio is a category called "Themes".  When I changed the theme here my colors finally changed.  This also explains why my screen switched to a black background.  It must have been the default color theme for Aptana when I installed it.  I guess the Aptana Studio themes override the default Eclipse color settings and also the "Color Theme" plugin I installed.

Comment: This happens in Apanta Studio too.